# How to create a zip archive from a bytes data in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to get a file data from a REST WS response, when I print the file data. I get something like:

```
PK  aB™OÉf         TestFile.txtÉÈ,V ¢D…’Ôâ…´ÌœT PK  aB™OÉf                 €    TestFile.txtPK      :   =
```

When I print the type of the file, I get the following:

```
<class 'str'>
```

I am having trouble writing the contents of the file data to a file path, I used the following approach in order to write the file data.

```
f = open(filename_path, 'w+',errors='ignore')
for chunk in file_data:
    f.write(chunk)
```

I also tried to convert the string data to bytes and tried writing it to file path without success. Please suggest me a way to overcome this problem.

```
bytes_file_data = file_data.encode()
with open(filename_path, 'w') as f:
   f.write('bytes_file_data')
```

This will return the file from WS response and then this is being passed as a parameter as file_data

```
response = get_data('get/file/' + str(token)) 

def get_data(urlPart): 
   URL = 'some/url/path+'urlPart
   headers = {'Content-Type':'application/json;charset=UTF-8'} response = 
   requests.get(url = URL, verify=False, headers = headers, auth=(requester,'')) 
   if response != None: 
      if response.text: 
          if isfile == True: 
              responsetext = response.text
return responsetext
```

Comment: `w+` is almost always the wrong filemode, use `w`

Comment: You have to read the result of the REST-Request as bytes. Please show that part of the code.

Comment: bytes_file_data = file_data.encode()
with open(filename_path, 'w') as f:
                f.write('bytes_file_data')
Even I tried with 'wb' without much success.

Comment: please show the code that generates `file_data`.

Comment: I am getting file_data as a response from WS in the form of :

PK  aB™OÉf         TestFile.txtÉÈ,V ¢D…’Ôâ…´ÌœT PK  aB™OÉf                 €    TestFile.txtPK      :   =

Comment: please show the code of your WS-call. There you find the error.

Comment: response = get_data('get/file/' + str(token))

def get_data(urlPart):
    URL = 'some/url/path'
    headers = {'Content-Type':'application/json;charset=UTF-8'}
response = requests.get(url = URL, verify=False, headers = headers, auth=(requester,''))
if response != None:
            if response.text:
                if isfile == True:
                    responsetext = response.text

Comment: please, edit your question. How does `responsetext` and `file_data` fit together?

Comment: responsetext  is returned from a different function and passed as a parameter file_data to the current method where I am trying to write this response.

Comment: `f.write('bytes_file_data')` is hopefully a typo. Remove the quotes from the name, and open the file with a `b` in the mode.

Comment: Why are you using `response.text` when the content isn't text?

Comment: Your question is not detailed enough. You need to provide both server and client side of a code, or at least description of that REST server you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `response.content` if you get binary data as result.
The `header` argument seems to be ignored by your REST server. You also don't have a websocket (WS) response, which was very confusing to me.

Simplifying to the basic parts, this should solve your problem:

```
def get_binary_data(url_part): 
    url = 'some/url/path/' + url_part
    response = requests.get(url=url, verify=False, auth=(requester, '')) 
    return response.content

file_data = get_binary_data(f'get/file/{token}') 
with open(filename_path, 'wb') as output:
    output.write(file_data)
```

Comment: I still have the same issue as earlier that after writing while I try to extract I get the error: The archive is corrupt, I believe I am doing something wrong while writing the data to the folder.

Comment: without further information about the service you call, nobody can help you.

Comment: Sorry for the late update. I was doing something wrong on my part that I figured it out but the above solution from Daniel help me resolve this issue. Thanks, Daniel & others for the prompt help.